# Dojo - don't repeat yourself

Tags: dojo, hide, slideshow, show, dry

Is there a simpler way to write something like this in dojo (instead of having a function for each thing i want to show or hide)? I know there must be a way to avoid such repetition but I'm not sure how to do it.

```
on(dom.byId("thing_toggle2"), "click", function(){
    if(thing_list2.style.display == "none") {
        thing_list2.style.display = "block";
        dom.byId("toggle2_sign").innerHTML = "(-)";
    } else {
        thing_list2.style.display = "none";  
        dom.byId("toggle2_sign").innerHTML = "(+)";   
    };
});

on(dom.byId("thing_toggle3"), "click", function(){
    if(thing_list3.style.display == "none") {
        thing_list3.style.display = "block";
        dom.byId("toggle3_sign").innerHTML = "(-)";
    } else {
        thing_list3.style.display = "none";  
        dom.byId("toggle3_sign").innerHTML = "(+)";   
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually decided to do this as a plain old javascript function which I can reuse elsewhere, including pages that might not need dojo. Something like this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:showlayer('myName');return false;">[1]</a>
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:showlayer('anothername');return false;">[2]</a>

<div id="myName" style="display:none;">Antonio</div>
<div id="anothername" style="display:none;">Elliot</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function showlayer(layer){
var myLayer = document.getElementById(layer).style.display;
if(myLayer=="none"){
    document.getElementById(layer).style.display="block";
    } else {
    document.getElementById(layer).style.display="none";
};

}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test this, but it should give you a starting point.  Adding an additional section, would just involve adding to the array of data.

```
var fnToggle = function(nodeMap) {
    var expand = domStyle.get(dom.byId(nodeMap.contentNode), 'display') == 'none';
    domStyle.set(dom.byId(nodeMap.contentNode), 'display', expand ? 'block' : '');
    html.set(dom.byId(nodeMap.expandoNode), expand ? '+' : '-');
};

var nodes = [
  { eventNode: 'thing_toggle2', contentNode: thing_list2, expandoNode: 'toggle2_sign' },
  { eventNode: 'thing_toggle3', contentNode: thing_list3, expandoNode: 'toggle3_sign' }
];

array.forEach(nodes, function(nodeMap) {
    on(dom.byId(nodeMap.eventNode), "click", function(){ fnToggle(nodeMap); });
});

// domStyle -> dojo/dom-style
// html     -> dojo/html
// array    -> dojo/_base/array
```

Comment: looks good, I would set "none" as the second option for display `expand ? 'block' : 'none'` and flip the +/- operators though `expand ? '-' : '+'`

Answer (score 0):

You could use [dojo/fx/Toggler](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/fx/Toggler.html#dojo-fx-toggler) which uses [dojo/_base/fx.fadeOut](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/_base/fx.html#dojo-base-fx-fadeout) and [dojo/_base/fx.fadeIn](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/_base/fx.html#dojo-base-fx-fadein)

Comment: I actually decided to do this as a plain old javascript function which I can reuse elsewhere, including pages that might not need dojo. Something like this: